# Sorting by boolean

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

What I want is to have the results being sorted by isTOP set to true at first and then the rest.

```
function getPlaces(){
    $result = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, short_description, photo_list, selected, recommended, isTOP 
            FROM place 
            WHERE id IN(SELECT id_place
                        FROM rubric_place 
                        WHERE id_rubric IN(SELECT id 
                                           FROM rubric 
                                           WHERE name = '".$_REQUEST["rubric"]."')
                       )  
            ORDER BY isTOP";
    getConnect();
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query){
        error100();
    }else {
        $result['code'] = 200;
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) { 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $result["places"][$i] = $row;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM rubric WHERE id IN(SELECT id_rubric FROM rubric_place WHERE id_place = ".$row[id].")";
            $queryModule = mysql_query($sql);
            if($queryModule){
                for ($k = 0; $k < mysql_num_rows($queryModule); $k++) {
                    $rowModule = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryModule);
                    $result["places"][$i]["rubrics"][$k] = $rowModule;
                }
            }
            $sql = "SELECT SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) AS rating FROM comment WHERE id_place = ".$row[id];
            $queryModule = mysql_query($sql);
            if($queryModule){
                $rowModule = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryModule);
                $result["places"][$i]["rating"] = $rowModule[rating];
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0`. So if you want true first, you need to use

```
ORDER BY isTOP DESC
```

Comment: thanx alot ! I know I should learn everything but still didn't do that